# iPhone SDK: Splash Screen Stretching

Tags: iphone

I have a splash screen in my app which is working fine other than the fact that the image seems to stretch slightly vertically when loaded.

The image is 320 x 460.

Any idea why the stretch is occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the splash screen size should be 320 × 4**8**0 (esp. if the status bar is hidden).

(You should also prepare a 640 × 960 one (`Default@2x.png`) for iPhone 4. You need to provide 2 or 3 more images if you need to support iPad as well. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1588.html for detail.)

Comment: As an addendum; the difference is probably the status bar.  The bar is displayed over the top of the splash screen, so you may just need a 20 pixel blank space at the top of the image to account for it.

Comment: 320x460 should work, but only if the status bar is visible at application launch. If you set `UIStatusBarHidden` in your `Info.plist`, then you’ll need a 320x480 version.

Comment: @Jeff, I find it easier to just use a 320x480 image, since it always works (i.e. you can change the status bar style without things breaking). Of course, things will break if the double-height status bar is showing (e.g. you're in a call).